# Large monitor for two notebooks (WinPC and Macbook Pro)

Tags: laptop, monitors, hdmi, windows, apple

I have two notebooks, one is Win10 PC (HDMI), second is Macbook Pro 15 Retina 2015 (HDMI, and two Thunderbolt 2's port).

Please recommend: one big monitor (30", 32" or biggest) with the ability to simultaneously connect two laptops, so that I can either switch between sources, or work in parallel (picture in picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, it is easier as we could see on the first spot.

Two trivial solutions:

1. Any monitor with at least 2 HDMI ports. Most of them (I estimate more than 50%) has multiple HDMI ports today.
2. Using a KVM extender, like [this](https://kvm-switch.de/images/product_images/original_images/DP02UR-F.jpg), to connect multiple laptops to the same display.

(2) has also the advantage, that you can use a single keyboard/mouse for both of your laptops.

Exactly which monitor(s) do you like you use, is already up to you (note, typically monitors live longer as the laptops, so a wise decision is relative more important).

Answer (score 1):

Samsung's 34 inch WQHD monitors like C34H890 are great for work, they have great picture and text quality, the support Picture-in-Picture and they are 21:9, so when you have two sources side-by-side, you get something close to 4:3. I have a similar monitor that I use in the same setup (Viotek GN34C), which is cheaper. It has an HDMI, DP and DVI input, but Samsung 34 inch monitors have HDMI, DP and USB-C/DP input, so you should be able to use them with your laptops.